# What is the physical significance of projectors vs. Pauli matrices in spin measurements?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-measurements

I am confused about the physical significance of projectors, e.g., $|u\rangle\langle u|$ for the "up" state $|u\rangle$ of a spin.

Let $|u\rangle =\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $|d\rangle =\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ be the up and down states of a spin.
We can distinguish between these orthogonal states by measuring spin along the $z$-axis, which corresponds to the operator
$\sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ - the first Pauli matrix. The eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$ : $\sigma_z|u\rangle
=|u\rangle$ and $\sigma_z|d\rangle =-|d\rangle$ .

So far, I seem to understand.

Now I know that any state can be written as a projector using the outer product of the state with itself, e.g. $|u\rangle \langle u|=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ .
I think I know the basic mathematical properties of projectors, but their physical significance as Hermitian operators, which should
correspond to measurements, confuses me: It seems that you can use $|u\rangle \langle u|$ to distinguish between $|u\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$
too. The eigenvalues of $|u\rangle\langle u|$ for these states are $1$ and $0$ : $|u\rangle\langle u||u\rangle =|u\rangle$ and
$|u\rangle\langle u||d\rangle =0|d\rangle$ .

Is that right? Which measurement corresponds to $|u\rangle \langle u|$ ? I thought I understood that any spin measurement
corresponds to a direction in 3d-space $\text{---}$ the 3 Pauli matrices standing for the $x,y,z$ directions, respectively. But what
3d-space direction does $|u\rangle \langle u|$ correspond to? If it does correspond to any direction, it should be the $z$
direction, right? But if both $\sigma_z$ and $|u\rangle\langle u|$ correspond to measurement along the $z$ -axis, what is the
significance of the eigenvalue pairs $1, -1$ vs. $1, 0$?

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The projection operator $|u\rangle\langle u|$ corresponds to the experimental question "Does the spin point in the positive $z$-direction - yes or no?" The outcome "yes" corresponds to the eigenvalue $1$ and the outcome "no" to the eigenvalue $0$ of the projection operator.

The operator $S_z=\hbar \sigma_z/2=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left( |u \rangle \langle u|-|d\rangle \langle d |\right)$ corresponds to the experimental question "What is the value of the spin measured in $z$-direction?" with the possible outcomes $+\hbar/2$ and $-\hbar/2$ as eigenvalues of $S_z$.

Both operators correspond to an experimental set-up, where the spin in $z$-direction is measured. As $|u \rangle \langle u|+|d\rangle \langle d|=\mathbf{1}$, the operator  $S_z$ can be expressed in terms of $|u \rangle \langle u|$ and the identity operator by $S_z =\frac{\hbar}{2} \left(2 |u \rangle \langle u|-\mathbf{1} \right)$ (and vice versa).

Comment: Thank you, your answer clears things up for me. Thinking about this in terms of questions asked by an experiment really helps. Your equation, which connects the two operators using the "decomposition of the identity" property of projectors, was new to me as well. Thanks a lot!